# How to add styles in tabs in react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs

In my project I'm using tabs from react-bootstrap. What I want do is get a bottom border in the selected tab.
[image]

But what I get is

[image]

Given below is my viewTicket.scss file

ViewTicket.scss

```
@import './../../styles/variables';
@import './../../styles/typography';

.icon-list {
    width: 120px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }


  .nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    // border: none;
  }
```

When I add `border:none;` then it looks like below

[image]

How can I add a line as in my design?Is it possible?

This is hw I use tabs in my project

```
<Tabs>
  <Tab eventKey={1} title="Comments"></Tab>
  <Tab eventKey={2} title="History" className="nav-item nav-link active"></Tab>
</Tabs>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  }
```

If you see your tab **bottom-border is more than text length**, you can remove the **padding left/right and add margin instead**.